# Cannot find name 'ol'

Tags: toggle, openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I am working for the first time on open layers (angular 4).
after installing and importing files in ts.

these are the imported files

```
  import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
  import View from 'ol/View.js';
  import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
  import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';

  new ol.Map({
```

I am getting this error
Cannot find name 'ol'.

Comment: This is Openlayers v5 code which requires npm to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new ol.Map({` should be `new Map({`, see [the simple map example in the documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html)

```
  import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
  import View from 'ol/View.js';
  import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';


  var map = new Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
```